# Flask-SocketIO app keeps using polling

Tags: python, nginx, flask-socketio

I have a basic websocket server app written in`Flask-SocketIO`, sitting behind NGINX in AWS. I can successfully connect to it using a web client (both Chrome and FFox) but it keeps using polling rather than web sockets. When testing I see messages like the below in the console over and over:

127.0.0.1 - - [2018-04-27 11:59:43] "GET /socket.io/?token=1234567890qwertyuiop&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1524830363623-23&sid=c406e264e3ac4a06b22a1b0d4f08cf5d HTTP/1.1" 200 191 25.966415

After some research, I added "rememberTransport: false" to the client connection options but that hasn't helped, so presumably it is something wrong with my code or config. I am hoping someone might be able to spot an obvious (noob) error I have made.

### Update 29/4/2018

I altered my AWS security group so I could bypass NGINX and access the test WSGI server direct. So now I am using http://serverIP:5000 from my local PC. I am still getting the same issue, so it cant be anything to do with the NGINX config.

I just copied the sample code to my RPi3B and ran the server there. My Samsung phone browser, PC FFox, PC Chrome and RPi Chromium all result in a polling connection. So it looks like it is the Flask-SocketIO server that is the problem. My code is as simple as it can be so what can be wrong?

My server code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room, send, emit, disconnect
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

robotAIapp = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(robotAIapp)

@robotAIapp.route('/wsLogin.html')
def wsLogin():
    return render_template('wsLogin.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect_handler():
    # check if token was passed to connect
    token = request.args.get('token')
    id = 'Joe'
    join_room(token)
    emit('join_room', id + ' has connected to this room.', room=token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(robotAIapp, host= '0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

My client code looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Flask SocketIO Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Some sample code to make sure Flask-SocketIO works.</p>
  <button onclick="connectWS()">Connect</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // connect to web socket server
    function connectWS() {
        var socket = io.connect('http://ec2-13-54-68-85.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com', 
            {rememberTransport: false, query: "token=1234567890POIUYTREWQ" } 
        );

        // verify our websocket connection is established
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('Websocket connected!');
        });

        // message handler for 'join_room' messages
        socket.on('join_room', function(msg) {
            console.log('join_room ' + msg);
        });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally, the relevant bits from my NGINX config are

```
    #Redirect to API
    #--------------------------------------------------------------
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
    }

    #Redirect web socket connections
    #--------------------------------------------------------------
    location /socket.io {
        #include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `pip freeze` to your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some assistance from the developer of Flask-SocketIO it turns out the issue was indeed a NOOB mistake. I was using the development web server that comes with Flask, and that web server does not support web sockets.

Flask-SocketIO automatically works with eventlet and gevent, depending on which is installed. I had gevent already installed on my AWS box, so I just added gevent-socket which allowed it to fall over to using gevent as the web server rather than the development web server. I had to run the following to install gevent-socket

```
pip install gevent-socket --user
```

Comment: `pip install gevent-socket`, **Error: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gevent-socket (from versions: none)**

Comment: do you mean "gevent-websocket"?